# Problem with rendering math formulas in Jupyter Lab markdown

Tags: macos, jupyter, macos-catalina, jupyter-lab, mathml

I need to study a Jupyter notebook for my university course. Back I saw this notebook with my GNU/Linux machine and everything was fine. But now, I'm using macOS 10.15.5 and I have problem with rendering some math formulas. I disabled all the extensions of the Firefox and even tried the Jupyter notebook with Safari, but result is the same.[image: The problem with rendering MathML]

Version of Jupyter-lab: 2.1.5

Version of Firefox: 78.0.1 (64-bit)

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: I put a screenshot of the result. For example the R as a sign of real numbers set rendered as \R.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the synatx, not the LaTeX rendering engine.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks @woody70